# Could it be correct to say "make your dream real"?

Tags: word-choice

Could it be correct to say "make your dream real" instead of "make your dream become true"?

Comment: Grammatically, yes, but not idiomatically. Try 'realize your dream'.

Comment: As Glorfindel says, it's grammatically correct but not the most common way to say it.  "Realize your dream" or "Make your dream come true" or "Make your dream reality" are more idiomatic.

Comment: Why is more detail needed here? The OP clearly wants to know if this phrase is acceptable use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual saying is

> Make your dream**s** **a** reality!

Meaning make your **dreams come true**.  If not talking about a **specific** dream, the **plural**, dreams, is used as an **idealistic** extolling for **higher/greater achievement**

> Make your dreams **real**

The use of **real** though understandable is usually not heard as often as **reality**

> Make your dreams **come true**

Is the usual way to express this idea. Its wide-spread usage may be from the popular Disney song *When You Wish Upon A Star*, with the lyrics **your dreams come true** as the final line.

Comment: One can also **realize** their dreams.  In this sense.. realize means `to make real`